# Chaining Angular Firestore Collections

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

This is hard to explain but I'll do my best. I have a database structure setup in Firebase like this:

User (Firebase User)

- Email

Connection

- Email
- Group
- Role

UserDetails

- Email
- First Name
- Last Name
- Address

Basically what I am trying to do is get the current user using AngularFireAuth, then query the User Details collection by user.email, and then query the Connections collection by user.email. Finally, map all this out to a User model and store that in an observable.

EDIT:

I have figured out how to get the first collection to the user observable but not sure where to go from here.

```
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        map(user => user.email),
        flatMap(email => this.afs.collection<User>(this.userRef, res => res.where('email', '==', email)).valueChanges()),
        mergeAll(),
        first()
    )
```

EDIT2:

So this is what I came up with and it's working BUT it just seems not right. I can tell there is a performance impact (albeit not that much). Probably won't ever use this for production but I'll continue using this solution as a proof of concept until I can find a better way.

```
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        map(user => user.email),
        concatMap(email => {
            return zip(
                this.afs.collection<Connection>('connections', res => res.where('email', '==', email)).snapshotChanges().pipe(mergeAll(), first()), 
                this.afs.collection<User>('users', res => res.where('email', '==', email)).snapshotChanges().pipe(mergeAll(), first())
            )
        }),
        map(([connection, details]) => {
            const a = connection.payload.doc.data() as Connection;
            const b = details.payload.doc.data() as User;
            return { ...a, ...b };
        })
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, I came up with this solution which does work. Probably not the best approach, but for a proof-of-concept project I am okay with it.

```
this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    map(user => user.email),
    concatMap(email => {
        return zip(
            this.afs.collection<Connection>('connections', res => res.where('email', '==', email)).snapshotChanges().pipe(mergeAll(), first()), 
            this.afs.collection<User>('users', res => res.where('email', '==', email)).snapshotChanges().pipe(mergeAll(), first())
        )
    }),
    map(([connection, details]) => {
        const a = connection.payload.doc.data() as Connection;
        const b = details.payload.doc.data() as User;
        return { ...a, ...b };
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

my initial approach to this would be to create 2 separate observables for user details and connection then use combineLatest to get the full user profile:

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

let connectionCollection$: Observable<DocumentChangeAction<T>[]>
let userDetailsCollection$: Observable<DocumentChangeAction<T>[]>
let user: UserModel;


this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        map(user => user.email),
        tap(email => {
            this.connectionCollection$ = this.afs.collection('connection', res => res.where('email', '==', email)).snapshotChanges()
            this.userDetailsCollection$ = this.afs.collection('userdetails', res => res.where('email', '==', email)).snapshotChanges() 
        }
)

combineLatest(connectionCollection$, userDetailsCollection$).subscribe(
    ([connection, userDetails]) => {
        //map the result to the user object e.g user.grandma = connection.grandma
    }
)
```

More examples of using combineLatest:

[Learn Rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)

Comment: I've tried this exactly how you suggested but I was not able to get this to successfully work. The connectionCollection$ and userDetailsCollection$ observables remain undefined which is really strange.

Comment: Hm, I would test if the authState pipe is emitting at first by logging out the user. Then check in the database if there's any valid email that is connected to that user

Comment: you could also use `forkJoin` for this. forkJoin will only emit values when all observables have produced at least one value